# How to use a jQuery variable that was just made inside a namespace?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I created a namespace to hold variables so that 2 different functions could use them.  My first variable uses jQuery and works fine.  The second tries to use the variable established in the previous line and fails.  It's undefined.

example:

```
varHolder = {
        buildStep4: $('#buildStep4'),
        jetSpan: buildStep4.find('#jetSpan')
    };
```

Is there a way to do this properly?

Comment: It seems you could simply do `jetSpan: $('#jetSpan')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can capture the value, but use a function to keep it scoped so it doesn't exist after you've created your object.

```
varHolder = (function() {
    var buildStep4 = $('#buildStep4');
    return { 
        buildStep4: buildStep4,
        jetSpan: buildStep4.find('#jetSpan')
    }
})();
```

You could also build your object piecemeal:

```
varHolder = {};
varHolder.buildStep4 = $('#buildStep4');
varHolder.jetSpan = varHolder.buildStep4.find('#jetSpan');
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I tried the piecemeal approach and it's working nicely.

Comment: @user1592980: I'm glad to hear it. If you found an answer to your question, please "Accept" the answer so that people know you don't still need help with this.

Answer (score 0):

Ids can't be duplicated inside a valid HTML document so it make no sense to provide context to an id selector, you can simply do

```
jetSpan: $('#jetSpan')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  You're correct, of course.  It's just that I'm building a one page app and my HTML code is getting long.